# How to say "In order not to make her angry but make her delighted"?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

I want to translate the following sentence to Japanese.

> In order not to make her angry but make her delighted, I must choose a proper gift for her birthday.

My attempt is as follows,

> 彼女は**怒られないように、または喜ぶために**、妥当な誕生日へのプルゼントを選ばなくてはならない。

Is it natural? Is there any other better way to say "in order not to make her angry but to make her delighted" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a causative verbal auxiliary せる like 彼女を怒らせるのではなく、喜ばせるために. 怒られない is passive form.

I feel 妥当な is a bit unnatural in this sentence and それ相応の may be more appropriate. And への in 誕生日へのプレゼント is extra.

Comment: 例文は「not A but B」であり、「not only A but B」ではないと思うのですが、どうでしょうか？

Comment: not only A but also B　として訳すと、「彼女を怒らせるだけではなく、喜ばすためにも」となり意味が変になり、そのように訳したつもりはないんですが、「not A but B」として「怒らせるのではなく、喜ばせるために」と訳した方がいいかもしれません。編集しときます。

Answer (score 1):

または means "or", so your sentence sort mean that you want her to not get angry OR get happy.

You might wanna use より(よりむしろ) instead. To mean "instead".

Also, I think that 怒られる would mean that someone gets angry at her. 怒る would mean that she gets angry.

> 彼女は怒るより、喜ぶために（ように）・・・